# How do I run facebook infer for my maven project?

Tags: facebook, build, facebook-infer

As mentioned in the documentation, I tried running

```
infer -- mvn compile
```

on my maven project. It complains as

```
[ERROR] Javac compilation error with:
['javac', '-g', '-d', ... <list of all jars> ...'-g', '-nowarn', '-target', '1.8', '-source', '1.8', '-encoding', 'UTF-8']
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: There is a maven plugin you might want to checkout: [anthemengineering/infer-maven-plugin](https://github.com/anthemengineering/infer-maven-plugin)

Comment: That `infer-maven-plugin` is dead.

Answer (score 5):

I works for me like this:

```
infer -- mvn package -Pdev
```

or

```
infer -- mvn -Dtest=DatabaseExportXlsTest test
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still get the same error with the first command. It seems you have some kind of profile named "dev" in your pom.xml
I am just looking for how I can use infer to tell about all problems in all of my source code.

Answer (score 1):

`infer -- mvn clean package` works for me.

The clean is important. If I run it without clean, I get `Nothing to compile. Try cleaning the build first.`

I suspect you could add -DskipTests, i.e. infer -- mvn clean package -DskipTests` to speed the build if you don't care about issues in your tests